# When i select first bottomnavigation menu item it select second menuitem

Tags: android, kotlin, menuitem, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

After Anything order I move to My Order bottom navigation menu then I select Home it selects My Order again not open home screen

[BottomNavigation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz8dI.png)

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_background_curve"
        android:paddingTop="35dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/selector_bottom_nav_icon"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
```

My Oncreate

```
    val navHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
        binding.bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Comment: Add your navigation graph and how you navigate to the My Order screen

Comment: Thank you so much❤ @ianhanniballake for your Quick response. problem solved now